# How to get "html title with id or more" using preg_match?

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I am using

```
preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);
```

to get

```
<title>Exapmle</title>
```

How can I get this using preg_match?

```
<title id="ANY_ID">Exapmle</title>
```

I am using this to get page title. Maybe, a title can have more than 'id'

 While answering, please keep that in mind.

---

Okey. Here is a complete code to get page title. Hope that it helps others.

```
function get_title($url){
     $str = file_get_contents($url);
     $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $str)); 
     // supports line breaks inside <title>
     $match = preg_match("/\<title(.*)\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title); 
     // tries to catch if the title has an id or more

     // if first prag_match gets an error 
     // (that means the title tag has no id or more)
     // it tries to get title without id or more
     if ($match === false) 
      {
         preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);
      }

return $title[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `(.*)` which match any characters. Note that last element of `$title` is your title

```
preg_match("/\<title(.*)\>(.*)\<\/title\>/i",$str,$title);
```